# How to run ansible playbook on boot on ubuntu?

Tags: boot, startup, ansible

I have installed Ansible on Ubuntu VM and it controls two more Ubuntu VMs. I want to run an ansible playbook when the ansible VM boots. I followed [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-run-script-on-startup-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-server-desktop#:%7E:text=The%20Ubuntu%2020.04%20is%20based,service%20during%20the%20system%20boot.), but it's not working for ansible playbooks. Also when the ansible playbook I'm trying to run requires Become Password after it's executed.

Answer (score 0):

**I would recommend you to show what you have tried and what difficulties you had.**
Create a service file:

```yaml
vi /etc/systemd/system/startup_playbook.service
```

You can execute the playbook directly in the Systemd unit file:

```yaml
[Unit]
Description=playbook
Before=motd-news.service
    
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=ansible-playbook /home/ubuntu/playbook.yml
StandardOutput=journal+console
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Run `systemctl daemon-reload` to reload units.
Start and enable the unit `systemctl enable --now startup_playbook.service`